# Sum all items in final row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
            BBG.XSWX.KABN.S BBG.XETR.TKA.S  BBG.XSWX.CON.S  BBG.XLON.ISAT.S
date                
20/02/2015  -0.004881       0.008011        0.007047       -0.000307
20/02/2015  -0.004881       0.008011        0.007047       -0.000307
17/02/2015  -0.005821      -0.016792       -0.016111        0.001028
18/02/2015   0.000588       0.019169       -0.000307       -0.001832
23/02/2015   0.007468      -0.011277       -0.003273        0.004355
```

How can I sum all the items in the final row of a dataframe (so that in this example I get -0.002727, which equals 0.007468 + -0.011277 + -0.003273 + 0.004355).

Comment: Code you tried so far?

Comment: Use the `sum()` method to sum the values over one of the axis. Choose which axis through the `axis` argument. Thus to get sums of all the rows do `a.sum(axis=1)`. If you only want one the rows, you can pick it as suggested by kronosapiens below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `iloc[-1]`:

```
In [3]:    
df.iloc[-1].sum()

Out[3]:
-0.0027269999999999985
```

Or [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html#pandas.DataFrame.tail):

```
In [8]:    
df.tail(1).sum(axis=1)

Out[8]:
date
2015-02-23   -0.002727
dtype: float64
```

The reason the `sum` needs `axis=1` is because `tail` returns a df whilst `iloc[-1]` returns a Series.

Answer (score 0):

Select the row using `.ix[]` syntax, and call `.sum()` on the resulting series:

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

In [2]: df.ix[2]
Out[2]: 
0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: 2, dtype: int64

In [3]: df.ix[2].sum()
Out[3]: 24
```

If you're having trouble using a datetime as an index value, you can use `.iloc[]` instead of `.ix[]` and pass an integer to access the row by location and not by value of the index.

```
In [4]: df.index = ['cat', 'dog', 'bear']

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
      0  1  2
cat   1  2  3
dog   4  5  6
bear  7  8  9

In [6]: df.ix['bear']
Out[6]: 
0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: bear, dtype: int64

In [7]: df.iloc[2]
Out[7]: 
0    7
1    8
2    9
Name: bear, dtype: int64
```